# ERROR creating stored procedure phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Need some help, my query is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE login(usern varchar(255),pass varchar (255))
      BEGIN                 

             SELECT * from usuario WHERE username = usern AND password = pass;

       END;
```

Throws

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4
```

Comment: Did you remember to use `DELIMITER //` or similar before attempting to define the procedure?

Comment: please look up how to do salted passwords never store plain text passwords.

Comment: i'll take the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @nick, when creating a stored routines set `delimiter` other than default `;`

```
delimiter $$

CREATE PROCEDURE login(usern varchar(255),pass varchar (255))
BEGIN                 

    SELECT * from usuario WHERE username = usern AND password = pass;

END $$

delimiter ;
```